# how to use Robot class in ruby to upload any file

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpCXo.png)
I need to automate Attach File button shown in image to upload file .Previously I have done  this  simply using  `.Send_Keys("file_name")` ,but its not working here.how do I upload file `.pdf/.jpg`in ruby ,
here is Html code -

```
<span class="trix-button-group trix-button-group--file-tools" data-trix-button-group="file-tools">
   <button type="button" class="trix-button trix-button--icon trix-button--icon-attach" data-trix-action="attachFiles" title="Attach Files" tabindex="-1">Attach Files</button>
   </span>
```

code which I have tried-

```
@driver.find_element(:css,"button.trix-button--icon-attach").click    
file = @driver.find_element(:id,"project_content")
file.send_keys("D:\download1.jpg")
sleep 5
```

Is there any way? Can we use Robot class in ruby .
also where can I find out ruby methods/class similar to Java ?

Comment: Not sure as to why you connect robot framework here, it's for Python I guess. You could use WATIR instead. It is a very sophisticated library.

Comment: @Rajagopalan I wanted to known the other ways to upload file because ```file.send_keys("D:\download1.jpg") ``` not working.

Comment: are you trying in WATIR?

Comment: I have written an answer. Check and let me know whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `file_field` method and `set` method.

```
require 'watir'

# create a browser object
browser = Watir::Browser.new

# navigate to the web page with the file upload form
browser.goto("https://example.com/upload")

# find the file input element by name, id, or other attributes
file_input = browser.file_field(name: "file")

# set the file path to the file input element
file_input.set("C:\\files\\test.png")
```